# Random.NextDouble и Random.Next не работают

Tags: c#

```
public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

Тут ошибку пишет:
Ошибка  CS1061  "Random" не содержит определения "Next", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Next", принимающий тип "Random" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

```
public string RandomString(int size, bool lowerCase)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
            builder.Append(ch);
        }
        if (lowerCase)
            return builder.ToString().ToLower();
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Тут пишет ошибку: 
Ошибка  CS1061  "Random" не содержит определения "NextDouble", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "NextDouble", принимающий тип "Random" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Помогите. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Посмотрите внимательней, от куда вы получаете класс `new Random()`. Скорей всего у вас есть другой класс с подобным названием, который вы и пытаетесь использовать. Напишите например `random.GetType();` и посмотрите какой будет результат, нужный вам класс должен выдать `System.Random`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!) И правда, класс называется Random

Comment: Сделайте ответ, чтобы я мог завершить вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Когда вам пишут, что в указанном классе нет того или иного метода/свойства, то тут скорей всего у вас есть нечто (класс), которое имеет аналогичное имя.

Например:

```
class Random {}
Random random = new Random();
```

Здесь идет обращение к созданному нами классу, не к системному, и у него естественно нет методов по типу `.Next()`.

Как определить, тот ли класс мы используем?
Ну я знаю как минимум два способа:

1. Просто навести на левую часть (до равно) в инициализации класса и студия сама выдаст нам все необходимое:

[image: class name]

2. Вы можете получить это название программным путем, написав просто `var type = random.GetType();` и дальше просто посмотрите на полученный результат, там будет тоже, что мы увидели и в первом варианте (`System.Random`).

Для того, что бы нам это все исправить и использовать нужное, в C# есть `namespace`, с помощью которых мы можем использовать нужный нам класс, даже если названия у них одинаковые:

```
class Random {}
System.Random random = new System.Random();
```

Либо мы можем задать нужный нам `namespace` в `using` (именем может быть что угодно):

```
using Random = System.Random;
```

Вот собственно и все. Следите внимательно за тем, что вы используете!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите внимательней, от куда вы получаете класс new Random(). Скорей всего у вас есть другой класс с подобным названием, который вы и пытаетесь использовать. Напишите например random.GetType(); и посмотрите какой будет результат, нужный вам класс должен выдать System.Random. – EvgeniyZ 34 минуты назад

Ответ в скопировал из комментов.